# Thumbnail image from MapView Annotation-iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, annotations, mkmapview

How could you get thumbnail from mapView as shown on in the red rectangle box the figure below.[image]

```
UIView *thumbnailContainer=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,64,64)];
    thumbnailContainer.clipsToBounds=YES;
    thumbnailContainer.layer.borderColor=[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5].CGColor;
    thumbnailContainer.layer.cornerRadius=3;
    thumbnailContainer.layer.borderWidth=1;

    Annotation *annotation1=[[Annotation alloc]init];
    annotation1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(29.7189214,-95.33916);
    annotation1.title = @"University of Houston";
    annotation1.subtitle = @"4800 Calhoun Rd,Houston";
    MKMapView *mapView2=[[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)];
    mapView2.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    mapView2.centerCoordinate=[annotation1 coordinate];
    [mapView2 addAnnotation:annotation1];
    //annPoint=[self.mapView convertCoordinate:annotation1.coordinate toPointToView:self.mapView];

    MKCoordinateRegion region=MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(mapView2.centerCoordinate, 150, 150);
    mapView2.region=region;
    mapView2.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75, 0.75);
    mapView2.layer.position=CGPointMake(thumbnailContainer.bounds.size.width/2,thumbnailContainer.bounds.size.height/2+10);
    [thumbnailContainer addSubview:mapView2];
```

Comment: When creating this thumbnail using iOS5 map kit you have to be careful not to hide google logo, or your app may be rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a scaled down map view? I don't think than creating a thumbnail image from the rendered layer of a map view would be a good solution, as it would require to load the map at the desired zoom first, and then, why not displaying directly this map instead of making an image out of it? :D This is the code I would use.

```
    Annotation *yourAnnotation = [[Annotation alloc] init];

UIView *thumbnailContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 64, 64)];
thumbnailContainer.clipsToBounds = YES;
thumbnailContainer.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5].CGColor;
thumbnailContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 3;
thumbnailContainer.layer.borderWidth = 1;

MKMapView *thumbnailMap = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)];
thumbnailMap.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
thumbnailMap.centerCoordinate = [yourAnnotation coordinate];
[thumbnailMap addAnnotation:yourAnnotation];

MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(thumbnailMap.centerCoordinate, 150, 150);
thumbnailMap.region = region;
thumbnailMap.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75, 0.75);
//we add 10 pixels on the y coordinate, to center the pin in the view. Moreover it will hide the "legal" label of the map view.
thumbnailMap.layer.position = CGPointMake(thumbnailContainer.bounds.size.width / 2, thumbnailContainer.bounds.size.height / 2 + 10);
[thumbnailContainer addSubview:thumbnailMap];
```

It looks like that: [image]

Comment: I have modified the code that you have posted but I could not able to generate the output. Please see my code above. Any help would be thankful?

Comment: What is this Annotation object you are using? Is it an actual subclass of some kind you created? In my example, Annotation is just there to represent the annotation object.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that it's a screenshot of the map, because any live maps in iOS contain the Google Maps logo in the bottom corner (

In order to do this, you need to work out the rect in the map that the pin resides in, and then use UIGraphicsContent() and such functions to screenshot the view. You can then put that image into a UIImageView so that it can be displayed by the user.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mapRect);    
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Alternatively, you could use the Google Maps Static API which allows you to receive a picture of the map at a specific location, using specified latitude and longitude values.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Comment: I think the static maps licence specifies it must only be used on websites